# Oracle - JSON_VALUE returns NULL

Tags: oracle, json-value

I have a JSON string as below, and when I run the following query, it does not return anything. The JSON is valid, so am I missing something?

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(json_content, '$.section_1') FROM messages;


{"section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"<p><b>Overview<\/b><\/p><p>Launched on 19\/06\/1992, the NUVEEN NEW YORK SELECT TAX-FREE INCOME (NXN) is a passively managed exchange traded fund designed to provide a broad exposure to<\/p>"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668):

> The function uses the path expression to evaluate expr and find a **scalar** JSON value that matches, or satisfies, the path expression.

Your path expression would return a JSON object, not a scalar, I believe. That's an error and the default behavior is to return null. You could try adding an `ERROR ON ERROR` clause and seeing if that raises an error.

Comment: What I am looking to finally do, is to retrieve the portion after "section_body".    There will eventually be a  "section_2" and it will have a "section_body" that I'll want to retrieve.   But I would think the query would return something......

Comment: I think `$.section_1.section_body` will return that element.

Comment: @LandonStatis - The query **does** return something: `null`. eaolson is right - if you want to retrieve a scalar string, namely the value associated with the key "section_body", you **can** do that with `JSON_VALUE`, exactly as eaolson showed you in the comment above this one.

Answer (score 0):

As eaolson stated, `JSON_VALUE` will only return a SCALAR value. If you want to return the JSON string contained in "section_1" you can use `JSON_TABLE` while using the keywords `FORMAT JSON`.

```sql
WITH
    messages
    AS
        (SELECT '{"section_1":{"section_publish":true,"section_body":"<p><b>Overview<\/b><\/p><p>Launched on 19\/06\/1992, the NUVEEN NEW YORK SELECT TAX-FREE INCOME (NXN) is a passively managed exchange traded fund designed to provide a broad exposure to<\/p>"}}'    AS json_content
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT j.*
  FROM messages
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE (
           json_content,
           '$'
           COLUMNS section1 FORMAT JSON PATH '$.section_1',
           section1_publish PATH '$.section_1.section_publish',
           section1_body PATH '$.section_1.section_body') j;
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks.   I tried using JSON_QUERY, like this:   SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_content, '$.section_1.section_body' ERROR ON ERROR) AS value FROM message;      But it just gives an error:   ORA-40441: JSON syntax error.      Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @LandonStatis - Why would you try using `JSON_QUERY()`? That function returns a JSON string, not a scalar value (a string, in your case). When the path given to `JSON_QUERY()` leads to a leaf node, you **must** use the `WITH WRAPPER` clause (hard-coded key words) right before `ERROR ON ERROR`, and the returned string **will** be enclosed in brackets; not quite what you need. Even `JSON_TABLE()` is overkill for what you need (if you really only need to extract **one** value from the whole JSON string); eaolson showed you how to do it with `JSON_VALUE()` in a comment to his answer.